# 2016 Macbook SSD not able to format

Tags: disk-utility, ssd

Laptop was working fine, then one day I turned it on and it booted up to the Question mark folder. In Disk Utility I tried to erase it just reinstall Catalina. When I try to erase it, it gets stuck on Creating Partition Map and then restarts to the Question Mark folder again. Tried resetting PRAM and SMC. Also tried diskutil in terminal as well as Disk Utility GUI,

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need hdiutil to get detailed information about what's wrong with your drive not diskutil.

Comment: The drive should have SMART support, shouldn't it?